# How do I put UISearchController Searchbar onto navigation bar with code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I embed the ViewController into a Navigation Bar, `navigationItem.titleView.resultSearchController?.searchBar` will put a search bar into the navigation bar. However, I've created a UISearchController and a UINavigationBar with code. This time, the navBar is showing up, but the searchBar isn't.

```
resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchBar.delegate = self

let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 375, height: 64))
self.view.addSubview(navBar)
//navBar.topItem = resultSearchController?.searchBar
self.navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
```

`navBar.topItem = resultSearchController?.searchBar` doesn't work because `topItem` is a String value and `resultSearchController?.searchBar` is a `UIView` type. How can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `UINavigationItem` instance and add it to the created navigation bar.
Add the search controller search bar to the UINavigationItem as titleView.

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addNavigationbar()
    }

    func addNavigationbar() {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
        self.view.addSubview(navBar)

        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "")
        self.searchController = searchControllerWith(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar

        navBar.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func searchControllerWith(searchResultsController: UIViewController?) -> UISearchController {

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        return searchController
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UIViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    }


}
```

Comment: There is no navigation bar creation in this code. This code works assuming you embed the VC into a nav bar. My question is how do I make the searchBar the titleView of a navBar I created with code