# Searchbar become hidden when navigating back

Tags: ios, swift

I am showing searchbar in home page. When I push a UIViewController then get back to home page, the searchbar become hidden.
here is my code

```
func setupSearch(){
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.placeholder = "Enter a search term...".localized()
        searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .search
        
        // Place the search bar in the navigation bar.
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController

        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
//        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        // Monitor when the search controller is presented and dismissed.
        searchController.delegate = self

        // Monitor when the search button is tapped, and start/end editing.
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.delegate = self

        /** Specify that this view controller determines how the search controller is presented.
            The search controller should be presented modally and match the physical size of this view controller.
        */
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: in viewDidLoad function

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797301/14359662