# Swift - UISearchController Does Not Activate - No Cursor - No Keyboard

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a UICollectionView with a header view inside of it and a UISearchController in the title of the navigation bar. This code has worked for other views yet does not work for this UICollectionView. I wanted to throw this out to the SO community to see if they can help me solve this problem.

```
class ViewBusinessProfile: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,  CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

 @IBOutlet var collectionViews: UICollectionView!

   
 var searchController : UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "search products..."
    //self.searchController.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
    self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    
    collectionViews.dataSource = self
    collectionViews.delegate = self

}

 func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
}
```

What can I do as far as debugging or anything to try to track down this problem? I have re-created the view in a new UICollectionView and the same problem occurs. The SearchBar is visible but not active to touch yet Back button works on the navigation bar.

[image]

These three views all have UISearchControllers on them and I segue between them. The one all the way on the right is where this problem is occurring. The same UISearchController code is used on the left two views and its works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I saw [in this related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797301/981049), I came up with this code:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addNavigationBarItems()
   }

    func addNavigationBarItems() {

        self.searchController = searchControllerWith(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func searchControllerWith(searchResultsController: UIViewController?) -> UISearchController {

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.delegate = self
        // searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        // dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation is deprecated as of iOS 12.0
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 150/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1) //rgb(10, green: 150, blue: 255)

        return searchController
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    }

}
```

This assumes a navigation bar already exists in the parent view controller (i.e. you don't have to create a new NavigationBar), and results should come out looking like this:

[image: Search Bar As Wide as Possible]

Comment: Using the provided code in the comment the search bar does not appear now and the UICollectionView is skewed in regards to image constraints

Comment: It is appearing in the view hierarchy maybe I need to increase the size

Comment: so that solution kind of works. The problem is that the search bar seems to be very very small and behind the current navigation bar. Tapping on the bottom of the default navigation bar does bring up a keyboard so the search bar is there yet incredibly small and behind the default nav bar.

Comment: You might need to use some Autolayout ([like what's seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430844/981049)) to make it wider.

Comment: so the problem is that the search bar that you helped me create is behind the default navigation bar. How do I bring the created search bar/navigation bar forward in front of the default navigation bar? or disable the default navigation bar?

Comment: There should only be one navigation bar (and the search controller should be in the navigation bar's title view). This sounds like a separate question from the one you started off with above.

Comment: This is what is showing in the view hierarchy from the code you have recommended to follow.

Comment: Maybe you can help me understand why if I set this created nav bar with a working search controller to the default nav bar it stops working?

Comment: What is wrong with the default nav bar that makes the search controller stop activating?

Comment: Am I exceeding the UINavigationBar stack? Because before this UICollectionView I have 2 UICollectionViews before it that also have UISearchControllers. Would this third view be exceeding the stack?

Comment: Let me know if what I've changed things to makes sense.  We shouldn't be creating multiple navigation bars :-)